# How can I access the names of variant products in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

How can I get the name of a variant product via the product repository? So for example t-shirt L. Or only the option.

This is my code:

```php
$cri2 = new Criteria();
$cri2->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $itemProductId));
$cri2->addFilter(new EqualsFilter("active", 1));
$cri2->addFilter(new RangeFilter('stock', [ 'gt' => 0 ]));
```

I need the name of this option:

[image: option image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finished code is:

```php
$cri = new Criteria();
$cri->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', "[YOUR PARENT ID]"));

// Add options to associations
$cri->addAssociations([
  'options'
]);

// Loop through variant products
foreach ($productRepository->search($cri, $context)->getElements() as &$variantRawItem) {
  
  // Map all options to array
  $options = array_map(function ($n) {
    return $n->get('translated')['name'];
  }, $variantRawItem->get('options')->getElements());

  // Create the options title
  $optionsTitle = implode(', ', $options);

  // $optionsTitle is now e.g.: L, Lila

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the confusion is here:

[image]

Just note that this is **not** the name of the variant, it's just it's options concatenated as preview.

You can see inn the picture below that the actual name is `null` & therefore inherits the parents' name:
[image]

If you change the name from the variant product, then it will not be `null` anymore.
[image]

To create an actual name you will have to manually pull its options using `associations`. Here is an example of a query you might be looking for. After you get the data, just create the name yourself out of the variation data. High chance that this is how Shopware6 does it in the picture provided.

```php
$criteria = (new Criteria()
            // loads non-child products
            ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('product.parentId', null))
            ->addAssociations([
                'options',
                'variation',

                'children',
                'children.options',
                'children.properties',
                'children.properties.group'
            ])
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, that customers that use our plugin are not been able to change this name, due the names comes from there erp systems. Do you know how to get the option as string?

Comment: adjusted answer with an example query

Answer (score 1):

When you want to search for a specific name you can use

```php
$cri2->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', 't-shirt L'));
```

When you want to search for the option name instead you can use

```php
$cri2->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('options.option.name', 't-shirt L'));
```

When you don't want to search by name, but only what to get the name of a given product:

```php
$product = $this->productRepository->search($cri2, $context)->getFirst();

echo $product->getName();
```

Comment: I want to only get the name. But with ->getName() only the name of the product and not the variant name is given out.